# Spring Service not starting Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have installed many backend services on Ubuntu system, but since today it does not work anymore.

In my spring application, I have written that the application should be executable (pom.xml)

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

After uploading to my server and trying to install the jar as a init.d service I get the following error message when trying to start.

```
Failed to start <myapp>.service: Unit <myapp>.service not found.
```

There are no logs or something. 
I installed the init.d service or in other terms I created a symlink with `sudo ln -s /var/myapp /myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp`.

Comment: I got the same issue. Do you have a solution？

Comment: yeah I solved it with "systemctl daemon-reload" afterwards started the service quite normal with service "<your_service> start". And of course "sudo" in front of every command.